# What is the difference between navigation.goBack() vs navigation.pop()?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Action wise both of these functions are doing the same work.

I checked `NavigationHelpersCommon` type from https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/types.tsx
It contains `goBack()` but not `pop()`

Reference from docs.

- [goBack()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#goback)
- [pop()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#pop)

On doing console.log() of navigation object available on props, I received this output. This lists functions available.

```
replace: ƒ ()
push: ƒ ()
pop: ƒ ()
popToTop: ƒ ()
goBack: ƒ ()
navigate: ƒ ()
reset: ƒ ()
setParams: ƒ ()
dispatch: ƒ dispatch(action)
isFocused: ƒ isFocused()
canGoBack: ƒ canGoBack()
dangerouslyGetParent: ƒ dangerouslyGetParent()
dangerouslyGetState: ƒ ()
addListener: ƒ addListener(type, callback)
removeListener: ƒ removeListener(type, callback)
setOptions: ƒ setOptions(options)
jumpTo: ƒ ()
```

Comment: `pop() ` removes current screen from the stack but on the other hand `goBack()` pushes the requested screen on top of the stack.

Comment: Any references/docs did you refer, that I am missing?